# Porting encryption method from Java to Python

Tags: java, python, encryption, aes, sha1

I can't receive the same output from my python code, what is my mistake?

i'm not sure but i make mistake in encode and decode process

```py
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random
import base64
from hashlib import pbkdf2_hmac
import binascii
import os
import datetime, time

def pad(byte_array):
    BLOCK_SIZE = 16
    pad_len = BLOCK_SIZE - len(byte_array) % BLOCK_SIZE
    return byte_array + (bytes([pad_len]) * pad_len)

key = pbkdf2_hmac(
hash_name = 'SHA1', 
password = b"75820705-2b7a-46dc-b811-0f6ad4ff33af", 
salt = os.urandom(8), 
iterations = 100, 
dklen = 384
)

auth_key = "d4eee068-272a-4aec-9681-5e16dcef6fbd";
timedate = x = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()-1000*10*60)
paylaod = auth_key+"|"+x.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.0000%f')[:-3]+"Z"


cipher = AES.new(key[:32], AES.MODE_CBC, key[32:48])
plain = pad(paylaod.encode("UTF-8"))
encrypted_text = cipher.encrypt( plain )

print (base64.b64encode(encrypted_text).decode("UTF-8"))
```

this is the working method on java

```java
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.*;

byte[] bArr = new byte[8];
new SecureRandom().nextBytes(bArr);
byte[] encoded = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1").generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(str2.toCharArray(), bArr, 100, 384)).getEncoded();
SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(Arrays.copyOfRange(encoded, 0, 32), "AES");

Cipher instance = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
instance.init(instance.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(Arrays.copyOfRange(encoded, 32, 48)));
byte[] doFinal = instance.doFinal(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));

ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byteArrayOutputStream.write(doFinal);
byteArrayOutputStream.write(bArr);
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
```

and this is the main of java:

```java
public static void main(String[] args)
{       
    String auth_key = "d4eee068-272a-4aec-9681-5e16dcef6fbd";
    SimpleDateFormat var0 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS'Z'", Locale.US);
    var0.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    String payload = auth_key+"|"+var0.format(new Date(Long.valueOf((new Date()).getTime()-1000*10*60))); //random key from /keys endpoint
    String outputVal = a(payload, "bd1676b5-5ce3-4351-a39b-36a7b7219c11"); //x-vmob-uid
    System.out.println(outputVal.replace("\n", "").replace(" ", ""));
}
```

The correct output is this:

```
Wgxc7xuqdKd2CqyT2KLE6ihankSTbTS/grIj+uyGG4IgpXWFxJ+KE4En/lQnL2vEu67w0sHeT6Tu1ibV0zahqpCKjw4pGPhhuCErS/8pojzg2TSMfFh7fw==
```

but i receive this:

```
8/VHDoMCOOI4Aaxus2nxridBPfm4Gvy2g8yRgK3VJUr3eSa3UucsAdzRMapuQj6pN3el12tqaAKYeNpFZCv5SuVosd4AYXwvmf/3uy5yr2U=
```

hope someone suggest me where to check or give me the error

Comment: can you also add the `import` part in Java? so that we can see what libraries are being used.

Comment: also, can you do a `pip freeze` and post the output in the question? so that we can see what packages in Python are being used.

Comment: I can see on the Python side when you create the key `key = pbkdf2_hmac(...` the salt argument is random `salt = os.urandom(8)`.  Then the key is used by the cipher.  So if you are using different salts how could the output be the same?  Also the payload is different because it's calculated from `time.time()` which will be different every run (and in Java the same reasoning should hold).  Note I don't know encryption, but that's what jumped out at me.

Comment: Your java code references str2 and str variables, but your code snippet does not show how these are initialized

Comment: @StevenRumbalski in java this:
 byte[] bArr = new byte[8];
new SecureRandom().nextBytes(bArr);
mean a random number generator

Comment: @Palamino you can just execute java code by copying the snippet code

Comment: @FreeWar when i run your Java code locally, it gives different result for each run. e.g. `VUnWoEYyKDphtUB7U2yS7hRLoou8Atu9f4CerOFkyI+EjpfUQ6MCqpb6NUzyvMoXap6o3E6GMTv1JCSFrgsfdngSM4sM9A1H8IFJe8ATTJcjf5mtCaV8mg==`

Comment: The point isn't that you aren't using randomization in both. The point is that randomization means your outputs will be different--not just between the two programs, but also from run to run.

Comment: yes, i know this but the output is different it length and in the last 2 characters!
When i call the output from java i get a 120 length with == but in python i have a 108 length word and only 1 '='
@StevenRumbalski

Comment: @JeffXiao the output is different each time but is the correct output "length and last 2 character"

Comment: @FreeWar answer added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

The reasons that you see differences in the result of Java vs. Python are:

1. different values are used in Java vs. Python for `pbkdf2_hmac`
2. the current time is used as part of the input, which changes between runs
3. `byteArrayOutputStream.write(bArr);` introduces a slighted longer string in Java output.

My guess is 3 is what you are looking for, but let me put out a long answer of thought process for above conclusions.

## Long answer

### Reproduce the issue

#### Complete Java source code that runs:

```java
package answer;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.Arrays;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;

import java.util.Base64;

public class SO56189889 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String auth_key = "d4eee068-272a-4aec-9681-5e16dcef6fbd";
        SimpleDateFormat var0 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS'Z'", Locale.US);
        var0.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

        // random key from /keys endpoint
        String formatted = var0.format(getSeedDate());

        String payload = auth_key + "|" + formatted;
        System.out.println(payload);
        String outputVal = magic(payload, "bd1676b5-5ce3-4351-a39b-36a7b7219c11"); // x-vmob-uid
        System.out.println(outputVal.length());
        System.out.println(outputVal);
    }

    public static Date getSeedDate() {
        Date now = new Date(Long.valueOf((new Date()).getTime() - 1000 * 10 * 60));
        return now;
    }

    public static String magic(String str, String str2) {
        try {
            byte[] bArr = new byte[8];
            // new SecureRandom().nextBytes(bArr);
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                bArr[i] = 'X';
            }
            String temp = new String(bArr);
            System.out.println(temp);

            byte[] encoded = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1")
                    .generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(str2.toCharArray(), bArr, 100, 384)).getEncoded();
            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(Arrays.copyOfRange(encoded, 0, 32), "AES");

            Cipher instance = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            // XXX: use Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE (was: instance.ENCRYPT_MODE)
            instance.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec,
                    new IvParameterSpec(Arrays.copyOfRange(encoded, 32, 48)));
            byte[] doFinal = instance.doFinal(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));

            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(doFinal);
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(bArr);

            System.out.println("no exception, everything OK");

            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            return "NOT WORKING";
        }
    }
}
```

Complete Python code that runs:

```py
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random
import base64
from hashlib import pbkdf2_hmac
import binascii
import os
import datetime, time

def pad(byte_array):
    BLOCK_SIZE = 16
    pad_len = BLOCK_SIZE - len(byte_array) % BLOCK_SIZE
    return byte_array + (bytes([pad_len]) * pad_len)

# salt = os.urandom(8)
salt = b'XXXXXXXX'
print(salt)
print('---------------')

key = pbkdf2_hmac(
hash_name = 'SHA1', 
# password = b"75820705-2b7a-46dc-b811-0f6ad4ff33af", 
password = b"bd1676b5-5ce3-4351-a39b-36a7b7219c11",
# salt = os.urandom(8), 
salt = salt,
iterations = 100, 
dklen = 384
)

auth_key = "d4eee068-272a-4aec-9681-5e16dcef6fbd"
x = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()-1000*10*60)
timedate = x
# payload = auth_key+"|" + x.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.0000%f')[:-3]+"Z"
payload = "d4eee068-272a-4aec-9681-5e16dcef6fbd|1970-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z"
print(payload)
print('-----------------')

cipher = AES.new(key[:32], AES.MODE_CBC, key[32:48])
plain = pad(payload.encode("UTF-8"))
encrypted_text = cipher.encrypt(plain)

result = base64.b64encode(encrypted_text).decode("UTF-8")
print(len(result))
print(result)
```

### Make sure input of Java program does not change

In above Java code, the variation come from:

- `getSeedDate()`
- `new SecureRandom().nextBytes(bArr);` in `magic()`

Let's change them:

```
public static Date getSeedDate() {
    Date seed = new Date(0L);    // 0L: the milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.
    return seed;
}
```

```
// new SecureRandom().nextBytes(bArr);
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    bArr[i] = 'X';
}
```

Now the Java output is always the same:
`Z6iTzNaJcDVdL5Rv8psb1D+xakq4By4KUxipmVv0ASjZUfIZO3nu+an5p27BxQ+x1+qoMLgD4vEub5PWcs69FDFy4y2etgiBCiCVnOM6RFlYWFhYWFhYWA==`

### Make sure input of Python program does not change

Change the following so that Python program uses the identical values of the Java program.

```py
# payload = auth_key+"|" + x.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.0000%f')[:-3]+"Z"
payload = "d4eee068-272a-4aec-9681-5e16dcef6fbd|1970-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z"
```

```py
# salt = os.urandom(8)
salt = b'XXXXXXXX'
```

```py
key = pbkdf2_hmac(
hash_name = 'SHA1', 
# password = b"75820705-2b7a-46dc-b811-0f6ad4ff33af", 
password = b"bd1676b5-5ce3-4351-a39b-36a7b7219c11",
salt = salt,
iterations = 100, 
dklen = 384
)
```

Note the `password` needs to be identical with what is in Java.

Now the Python program always output:
`Z6iTzNaJcDVdL5Rv8psb1D+xakq4By4KUxipmVv0ASjZUfIZO3nu+an5p27BxQ+x1+qoMLgD4vEub5PWcs69FDFy4y2etgiBCiCVnOM6RFk=`

### Compare the results

Java `outputVal.length()` is 120, and Python `len(result)` is 108.

Let's see them together:

Java:
*Z6iTzNaJcDVdL5Rv8psb1D+xakq4By4KUxipmVv0ASjZUfIZO3nu+an5p27BxQ+x1+qoMLgD4vEub5PWcs69FDFy4y2etgiBCiCVnOM6RF***lYWFhYWFhYWA==**

Python:
*Z6iTzNaJcDVdL5Rv8psb1D+xakq4By4KUxipmVv0ASjZUfIZO3nu+an5p27BxQ+x1+qoMLgD4vEub5PWcs69FDFy4y2etgiBCiCVnOM6RF***k=**

### Try and error

At this point, i notice that in Java, you have `doFinal` and `bArr`,

```
byteArrayOutputStream.write(doFinal);
byteArrayOutputStream.write(bArr);
```

Whereas in Python, you only use the `plain`

```
plain = pad(payload.encode("UTF-8"))
encrypted_text = cipher.encrypt(plain)

result = base64.b64encode(encrypted_text).decode("UTF-8")
```

An experiment shows removing the `byteArrayOutputStream.write(bArr);` in Java generates the exact string as Python.

### After thoughts

- make sure the inputs are the same before you compare the results
- double check the strings you use
- try-and-error can actually work in some cases

Comment: i'm really stupid hahahaha i haven't noticed the "byteArrayOutputStream.write(bArr);"
Just added it in my byte array and all work good!
Thanks bro